# How do you show only the contents of a Google Doc (not the whole website) with a WebBrowser?

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-scraping, google-docs

I have a `WebBrowser` in my program

I've set the `WebBrowser` to navigate to a Google Document on [Google Docs](https://www.google.com/docs/about/). Everything works perfectly fine, however, I want to display **only** the ***contents*** of this Google Document.

I'm thinking of using [Web Scraping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping), which uses *this code*

```
Dim pos1 As Long, pos2 As Long, final As String
Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://mygoogledocument/")
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim datastream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream
Dim reader As New StreamReader(datastream)
Dim strData As String = reader.ReadToEnd

pos1 = InStr(strData, "anytext", vbTextCompare)
pos1 = InStr(pos1 + 1, strData, "", vbTextCompare)
pos2 = InStr(pos2 + 9999, strData, "", vbTextCompare)
final = strData.Substring(pos1, pos2)

TextBox1.Text = final
```

but getting the numbers right to tell my program exactly what to scrape is too time-consuming, and this is a task which is due soon.

Is there any way I wouldn't have to use a `WebBrowser`, and use something a little easier instead? Is there a way to export a Google Document, and display it's contents in a `TextBox` with all of the colors and font formatting?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to web scrape google drive. They have pretty good API coverage and documentation.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads

I suggest you just download the verbatim file using the api and then just pull the contents from the file into your application as you would normally.